# Extract a string between two words

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract hash from string below which is `e5e1af55bad959546ec7608cc8685fe67bc5426e`

```
$word1 = 'btih:';
$word2 = '&dn';
$magnet = "[magnet:?xt=urn:btih:e5e1af55bad959546ec7608cc8685fe67bc5426e&dn=The+Deadly+Game+2013+DVDRip+XviD-EVO+&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337]";
if(preg_match('/'.preg_quote($word1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($word2).'/is', $magnet, $match)){
$upper = strtoupper($match['1']);
$generated = "http://torrage.com/torrent/".$upper.".torrent";
}
```

in above code, the hash are located between `btih:` and `&dn`
can i know why my code doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
'/(?<=btih:)(.+?)(?=&dn=)/'
```

This means capture a string which is preceded by `bith:` and followed by `&dn=`

Alternatively you can avoid lookbehind and use:

```
'/:btih:\K(.+?)(?=&dn=)/'
```

Here `\K` is used to reset matched pattern.

As an another alternative you can avoid `lookahead` also and use:

```
'/:btih:(.+?)&dn=/'
```

And use matched `group #1`

Comment: works!!! thank you bro.. really2 fast answer and solved my problem..
I read some tutorial in understanding regex. but it too confusing.. I had no choice but ask here.. thank you again :) you saved my day

Comment: I got another problem.  I tried with the example I gave in the question and it works.. but doesnt work with my real situation

this is my real code --> http://pastebin.com/qrmTyWJU ..
$result['10'] is an array --> http://pastebin.com/19j8d4z9 ..
why the regex cant detect the hash?? I splitted them using explode and result for $result['10'] is the magnet link exactly like example in the question

Comment: Let me take a look and suggest.

Comment: Im sorry.. $result['11'] will output "1"..
the magnet link at end is not part of the array.. the magnet link is the result of echo $explode['1']

Comment: @G3M: See **working demo: http://ideone.com/JzeKt1** I suggest you to create your code on ideone to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Ow, yeah, true, my bad... could you show us the code creating `$result[]` maybe

Comment: http://chopapp.com/#ixf4vgsi this is $result output.. I am using explode to separate magnet link from other word exists in the array $result['10']

Comment: @G3M: If you are running into issues, feel free to create a sample code on ideone.com so that I can attend it.